# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error? La aplicación Firebase comprueba el token no válido en android flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-auth, firebase-storage

Estoy implementando la verificación de aplicaciones en Android Flutter pero encuentro este error. [image: error de consola]

intente de esta manera
si  `(kDebugMode)`

`await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate` 
  `androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,`

`await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate` 
androidProvider:AndroidProvider.playIntegrity, ```

prueba de esta manera

`FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate (androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,);`  y prueba de esta manera

`FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();`

Lo tengo registrado en mi consola App Check [image: app check consola]

necesito que me ayudes con una solución por favor